# Fetch posts from Wordpress Api with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch posts title form WP API with Vuejs but console throws me an error

> Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined"

I don't know what is a problem. Here is posts component:

```
<template>

<div class="posts">
            <h1>Posts</h1>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                     {{ post.title.rendered  }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.getPosts();
        },

        data() {
            return {
                postsUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
                posts: [],
                postsData: {
                    per_page: 10,
                    page: 1
                },

            }
        },
        methods: {

            getPosts() {
              axios.get(this.postsUrl, {params: this.postsData})
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.posts = response;
                          this.configPagination(response.headers);
                    })
                    .catch( (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `response` object in `axios` includes multiple properties like `headers`, `status` and `data`, in your case the your posts are the `data` property, so set `this.posts = response.data;` :

```
     .then((response) => {
                    this.posts = response.data;
                      this.configPagination(response.headers);
                })
```